# Relationship with recvfrom, sleep

Tags: networking, udp

I don't know exactly,
In my case.

I was tested UPnP via Linux, I just use recvfrom.

I got a HTTP response not expected counts. (In this time, I expected 3)

So, I do put sleep(1) in while(), It works!

I have a question is 'why'?

recvfrom returns to buffer per one packets. <-- this is what I know, and is there a relationship with this?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are asking, can you try to clarify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recvfrom() function for both connection and connection-less sockets.if you are using this function in connection-less socket, If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, the excess bytes are discarded. To avoid this kind of situations **"you can set the flag MSG_WAITALL that Requests the function block until the full amount of data requested can be returned. The function may return a smaller amount of data if a signal is caught, if the connection is terminated, if MSG_PEEK was specified, or if an error is pending for the socket."**

if you are using recvfrom() function in a stream-based sockets such as SOCK_STREAM, message boundaries are ignored. In this case, data is returned to the user as soon as it becomes available, and no data is discarded.

In your case , instead of using sleep() you can set MSG_WAITALL flag that will block your socket untill full amount of data requested can be returned. and there is no relationship between recvfrom() and sleep() functions.

Comment: MSG_WAITALL doesn't help in the UDP case where the supplied buffer is too small. It can't. Nothing can. It helps with TCP sockets where the intent is to fill the buffer. There is nothing here that actually answers the question, whatever  it is. -1